# FosRestBundle PATCH action prevent update entity with null/default values

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have made a working `patchAction` on my `serverController` to update one or some field in a existent server.

Actually my `patchAction` look like this

```
/*
 * @ParamConverter("updatedServer", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function patchAction(Server $server, Server $updatedServer, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
{
    if ($validationErrors->count() > 0) {
        return $this->handleBodyValidationErrorsView($validationErrors);
    }

    $server->setAlias($updatedServer->getAlias())
        ->setMac($updatedServer->getMac())
        ->setSshUser($updatedServer->getSshUser())
        ->setSshPort($updatedServer->getSshPort())
        ->setIpmiAddress($updatedServer->getIpmiAddress())
        ->setIpmiLogin($updatedServer->getIpmiLogin())
        ->setIpmiPassword($updatedServer->getIpmiPassword())
        ->setMysqlHost($updatedServer->getMysqlHost())
        ->setMysqlRoot($updatedServer->getMysqlRoot())
        ->setWebServer($updatedServer->getWebServer())
        ->setWebServerSslListen($updatedServer->getWebServerSslListen())
        ->setWebServerSslPort($updatedServer->getWebServerSslPort())
        ->setMysqlServer($updatedServer->getMysqlServer())
        ->setSuphp($updatedServer->getSuphp())
        ->setFastcgi($updatedServer->getFastcgi())
        ->setNadminCompliant($updatedServer->getNadminCompliant())
        ->setEmailCompliant($updatedServer->getEmailCompliant())
        ->setAvailable($updatedServer->getAvailable())
        ->setEnvironment($updatedServer->getEnvironment())
        ->setInstalledAt($updatedServer->getInstalledAt());

    if (null !== $updatedServer->getOs()) {
        $os = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Os')->findBy(['id' => $updatedServer->getOs()->getId()]);
        $server->setOs($os[0]);
    }

    if (null !== $updatedServer->getPuppetClasses()) {
        $puppetClass = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:PuppetClass')->findBy(['id' => $updatedServer->getPuppetClasses()[0]->getId()]);
        $server->setPuppetClasses($puppetClass);
    }

    if (null !== $updatedServer->getPuppetTemplates()) {
        $puppetTemplate = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:PuppetTemplate')->findBy(['id' => $updatedServer->getPuppetTemplates()[0]->getId()]);
        $server->setPuppetTemplates($puppetTemplate);
    }

    if (null !== $updatedServer->getBackupModel()) {
        $backupModel = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:BackupModel')->findBy(['id' => $updatedServer->getBackupModel()->getId()]);
        $server->setBackupModel($backupModel[0]);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($server);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->view([$updatedServer, $server]);
}
```

The problem is when trying to update only one or few fields. I set a JSON body to change datas.

```
{
    "mac": "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
}
```

The JSON body will look like this after I send the request

```
// This is what $updatedServer get in my controller
{
    "id": null,
    "name": null,
    "alias": null,
    "notes": null,
    "hosted_domain": null,
    "mac": "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",
    // ...
}
```

As you can see above in my controller I have set every updatable fields

```
$server->setAlias($updatedServer->getAlias())
    ->setMac($updatedServer->getMac())
    ->setSshUser($updatedServer->getSshUser())
    // ...
```

So if a value is `null` inside the body request the controller will set it to `null`, it will do the same with the default values set inside the entity

I had the idea to make a `if` condition for every updatable fields but I will have **>20** conditions inside...

How can I prevent this to append with a generic and reusable system ?

Can these values can be ignored if they are not set before the execution of the request ?

Maybe create `callback` inside my entity class ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

My `Server $server` is the current server object I want to update. It's coming with the request. Exemple when I send this request `/api/servers/2` I get the body of the server with the ID `2`.

The `Server $updatedServer` is the body with the updated datas.

I tried your second edit but I get a `500 error`

> "Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information."

Because I can't get the server I want to patch and the body (with `ParamConverter`) in the same time.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer to that question

Use a set parameter function in your entity which will update the field that you will give in your request body

App\Entity\Server

```
use Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector;

public class Server {

    public function setParameters($params) {
        foreach ($params as $k => $p) {
            if (!is_null($p)) { // here is the if statement
                $key = Inflector::camelize($k);
                if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
                    $this->{'set' . ucfirst($key)}($p);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

App\Controller\ServerApiController

```
public function patchAction(Server $server, Request $request, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
{
    if ($validationErrors->count() > 0) {
        return $this->handleBodyValidationErrorsView($validationErrors);
    }

    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $em->persist($server->setParameters($data););
    $em->flush();

    return $this->view([$server]);
}
```

It should return the content of server + the field update by the body of your request which will be change in the $server->setParameter($data)

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this by using the `PATCH` method as [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) explain it (the right way).

As its name sounds, a `PATCH` method is used to send a patch that updates an existing resource.

To use it correctly, you need to send the whole new state of your resource.
In other words, you must send all the properties of your resource, those unchanged included.

So, if you send each property with its corresponding value, your patch will be correctly applied.

Example:

```
{
    "id": 1, # Identifier, never change
    "name": [oldValue],
    "alias": [oldValue],
    "notes": [oldValue],
    "hosted_domain": [oldValue],
    "mac": "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",
    // ...    
}
```

Like so, no need of write a check per property.

There is a good reference to this common bad usage that is [Don't PATCH like an idiot](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) from William Durand.

**EDIT**

I was wrong.

You don't need to update your resource entirely to use PATCH correctly.
You need to send a set of changes, like described in the link given.

The better advice I can give you is to use a [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/request_body_converter_listener.html) that retrieves your object by its identifier and do the update for you depending on fields you give it.

**EDIT2**

I mean:

```
/*
 * @ParamConverter("server", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function patchAction(Server $server, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
{
    if ($validationErrors->count() > 0) {
        return $this->handleBodyValidationErrorsView($validationErrors);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($server);
    $em->flush();
    
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, you need an Assembler object used as intermediary step for the merge.
See this great example of [handling PATCH requests through FOSRest](http://fr.slideshare.net/fightmaster/handle-complex-postpatch-requests-in-restful-api).

Comment: Can you explain a little more this `use a ParamConverter that retrieves your object by its identifier` ? I don't really get what this mean. I searched on [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/request_body_converter_listener.html) doc but this didn't help me more.

Comment: I just see that you are already using a ParamConverter. Can you say me from where does your `Server $server` is coming from ? Why not make the ParamConverter converting `server` rather than `updatedServer` instead of calling setters manually ?  This will update your resource directly from the request body after validation, and BTW avoid the problem.